# Query mongodb using internal field

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection: people.
I wish to query documents where people.lastname = people.firstname

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sergio correctly points out, [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/) has poor performance, but if that's still acceptable to you, this is how you'd do it:

```
db.people.find( { $where: "this.lastname == this.firstname" } );
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible at the moment (in efficient manner). It might be possible using `$where` but it has terrible performance and I wouldn't advise using it in real applications.